How long should the "beta" tag remain?
I recommend to remove the "beta" tag from "Quantitative Finance beta".
"Beta" makes the site less sincere and professional. The "beta" version remained for some years now, I dont see why it should be called beta anymore.

Also check out this post by Ana: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/266114

We actually don't decide when to leave Beta.
Our site's stats are tracked on Area51 and you can see them here.
I'd say we have a good number of visits, but as you see our percentage of answers needs work as well as the number of questions per day, which is closer to the "Needs work" grade than the "Excellent" grade.

Sometimes sites organize initiatives where they rally the community to address unanswered questions. You may want to consider something like that for Quant SE.

@Ana I have to say it seems not fair to compare Quant.SE with the other main SE sites to determine its Beta status, since the Quant area is quite specialized and not a "mass" product. In my opinion Quant.SE is the best Q&A site relative to other sites in this field and this should be the correct measure. Simply judging a site based on absolute size is really not a full picture.

I agree with you, and the Community Team's thinking on this has been shifting recently.

Everything SRKX said is accurate, but while we're at it, I want to clarify that Area51 stats are not the only criteria Stack Exchange uses to determine whether a site graduates. 
What else is there? For one thing, does the community engage in self-governance, hashing out site policies on meta? Is there plenty of voting and editing? What is user retention like? These are indicators of site health, and we take them into account too. 
This is because our goal is to create an archive of knowledge about quantitative finance -- a place on the internet filled with canonical information about this subject. When you post here, you are helping a future person who is struggling with the same question you struggled with. It is a collaborative endeavor, and to achieve, we've found it requires thinking about the humans behind the posts, as well as the numbers. 
If you're looking to graduate, its wise to keep an eye on Area51 stats, but don't don't stop there. 

I agree with the OP that it is really frustrating to see that we are still in the beta phase - how do you see it: are there any chances that we will get out of it soon? Thank you :-)

A quick update to let you know that Quant has met the criteria for graduation  (according to a note by the Stack Exchange Community Team).
In other words, we are going to leave Beta soon! The exact graduation date is not yet known though.
Anyway, congratulations and thank you for all your hard work and dedication building the QE community! 

Is this your interpretation or where did you find it? I could not find a reference to our site there?!?

@vonjd: The site moderators received a notice from the Stack Exchange Community Team about a month ago. Verbatim, "this is a done deal but the schedule is still in flux".
